# SQL Server : set a variable in CASE statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to set a variable in a case statement? My code doesn't work. Thanks all.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spReport
@q1 INT,
@q2 INT
AS
BEGIN

-- Dates for the 2 different quarters to be viewed
DECLARE @StartDateQ1 DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDateQ1 DATETIME
DECLARE @StartDateQ2 DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDateQ2 DATETIME

SELECT
CASE @q1
    WHEN 1 THEN SET @StartDateQ1 = '20130401'
END
```

Comment: In T-SQL, `CASE` is an **expression** that returns a value - you cannot have code blocks in your `CASE` statement. See Martin's answer how to deal with that.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use

```
SET @StartDateQ1 = CASE @q1
                     WHEN 1 THEN '20130401'
                   END
```

to set the value of a single variable according to a `CASE` expression.

If your real logic is more complicated (e.g. need to set multiple variables inside a condition) look at `IF ... ELSE` instead.

`CASE` is an expression not a flow of control construct.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another way to solve this using an IF statement:

```
IF @q1 = 1
BEGIN
    SET @StartDateQ1 = '20130401'
END
```